# Trying to use a columns value as a key to a different column for my results id like to output

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have two columns per event I am trying to use. Well call these `col1` and `UknownRandomColumnName` (`urcn` for short) .

The key of `urcn` changes from event to event and is unknown prior to search time, but the value of `col1` will always be the key of `urcn`.

How can I use the value of col1 as a key for the data id like to output from `urcn` in a search. Example data for my events may look like in a table:

```
==============================
|  col1   |  urcn1 |  urcn2  |
==============================
|  urcn1  | Value_1|         |
------------------------------
|  urcn2  |        |  Value_2|
------------------------------
```

Here is an example sample of the events:

```
{
type: "fwagods",
fwagods: {
    name:"someNameHere",
    age:23
    }
},
{
type: "zsaf",
zsaf: {
    name:"someName2",
    age:65
    }
},
{
type: "smorflafaum",
smorflafaum: {
    name:"SomeName3",
    age:41
    }
}
```

The query of the table inputs should produce:

```
Value_1
Value_2
```

The query of the event format inputs should produce:

```
name: someNameHere, age: 23
name: someName2, age: 65
name: SomeName3, age: 41
```

Comment: What should be the output of your query?  What is the desired result?

Comment: A table with the values of the `ucrn` columns

Comment: Please see if I got it right and {Edit] for clarification if neccessary.

Comment: Interesting task. I found *almost* the answer https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Read-a-field-value-which-field-name-is-in-another-field/m-p/494681 but could not compensate for its limitations.

Comment: Are those unknown column names completely random or do they follow any pattern that separates them from other fields?

Comment: They are random to my knowledge there is not a pattern in their naming. Investigating your link now thank you very much pm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246071/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-tilted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I was able to solve this issue. We know the property names of the child values inside of the object we do not know the key for. With this in mind we are able to use the `rex` method and extract the values from the _raw field.

```
| rex field=_raw "name\":\s?\"?(?<new_name>.*?)\"?(,|})" | table new_name
```

would output

```
someNameHere
someName2
SomeName3
```

Credit and thanks to @PM 77-1 for helping me talk through this.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer.